# Why is this code to update a users password not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, pdo

> ```
> <?php
> include_once 'db.php';
> session_start();
> if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
>   die('You are unauthorized to be here. 1');
> }
> $old_password = md5($_POST['old_password']);
> $new_password = md5($_POST['new_password']);
> $sql = "UPDATE users SET pass='?' WHERE user='?' AND pass='?'";
> $q = $db->prepare($sql);
> $q->bindParam(1, $new_password);
> $q->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['username']);
> $q->bindParam(3, $old_password);
> $q->execute();
> header('location: ../?page=account');
> ?>
> ```

Here's my 'users' table scheme:

```
 `users` (`active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
          `user`   varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `pass`   varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `admin`  int(1) NOT NULL,
          `date`   varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'error',  
          `Paid`   varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
          KEY `user` (`user`) )
 ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Its simply not updating the values at all... Any ideas?

Comment: is it throwing any error???

Comment: pass='?' WHERE user='?' AND pass='?' does not need quotes ..

Comment: If you have error reporting on it will tell you why the query is not updating

Answer (score 3):

Remove quotes from your placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET pass='?' WHERE user='?' AND pass='?'";
```

change it to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET pass=? WHERE user=? AND pass=?";
```

Comment: I think adding quotes is not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your code does not have a typo or other bug (not tested), logically the only explanation is that either the username or old password are not matching